# Slack bot private channel post messages

Tags: javascript, slack, slack-api, botkit, slack-commands

I'm developing a slack bot for my company. I can't find any information on this topic - when a user types slash command in private channel how to make similar response from slackbot `To use /github, add @GitHub to this conversation.`?

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you please add any attempts made?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Everyone here is ready to help you with your question, but can you please be a bit more specific what you issue is? Do you want any response to a slash command or do you also want to be able to check if your bot user is the member of the current channel? Please also add your current best code to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really sorry I was so indescriptive... So, the issue was - I built a bot that subscribes slack channel for some notifications (some actions in our project). When user types slash command in private channel, it's actually possible to answer him with ephemeral (visible only for him) messages, so there wasn't any problem with subscription procedure. But when some action happened on our side, it was impossible to send message with `chat.postMessage` in that private slack channel (`error:channel_not_found`) because of slack restrictions. 
When you use github or asana slash command in slack private channel - you will receive response from **slackbot** `To use /github, add @GitHub to this conversation`. And I was curios - is it possible to make similar answer from **slackbot**. But it figured out it's impossible, you have to make answer from your own bot. 
It was a little tricky - you don't have any access to slack private channels, and one solution I found was to get the list of all workspace private channels where our bot was already invited `groups.list`. And if the current channel where user was typing slash command is not in that list - notify user, that he has to add bot to the channel `/invite @bot`.
Sorry for my english... And i hope maybe it will be helpful to someone, who will encounter same problems...